# Split the string using regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a innertext like

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  hi</br>
  This is a multiple line</br>
  code
</div>
```

I want to make it a single line and instead of 
 take space and split it with comma..
I tried `sTextbox.split(/[\s,]+/);` but it include new line also
please suggest me to solve this problem

**UPDATED**
Expected output is like :
`hi this is a multipleline code`..
I have to calculate `sTextboxSplit[sTextboxSplit.length - 1]` and it gives `sTextboxSplit = ["hi", "this", "is", "multiple","line","code" ""],` and in this it will give `""` as my last index where it my last index is `code`.
I want to work this in c# mvc..

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Please add more details to your question, show expected output and can you provide us with something you've tried already in JSFiddle?

Comment: At first, you should know that http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2956006

Comment: why not use `sTextbox.split(/[ \t]+/);` instead.

Comment: @RishabhSinghBisht it gives `sTextboxSplit = ["bedrom0_1", "people", "view↵t↵"],` of text `sTextbox = "bedrom0_1 people view↵t↵"`..`↵`is an enter =new line that is not splitted

Comment: Its unclear. I though you don't want to split on new line. Do you want to split new line or not? Your code should work if you want to split new line.

Comment: @RishabhSinghBisht I want to ignore new line and make it space instead of new line

Comment: `sTextbox = sTextbox.replace("\n"," ");` first then `sTextbox.split(/[\s]+/);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
>([^<]*?)<
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU9sA8/1)

This regex use [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
to match any thing between `>` and `<` except `<`.

Comment: My sTextbox value is `sTextbox = "bedrom0_1 people view↵t↵` and after applying ur suggestion m getting same ans..